# Match inside match - ocaml raises syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

Does anyone know why this function raises the syntax error? I haven't provided my written side functions, since they are probably not that relevant here, since it's revolving around proper syntax.

I tried deleting the brackets that raised the error (which I think.. should be there?), only to then raise another syntax error one line lower, at the begining of the row with the line "|".

```
type 'a grid = 'a Array.t Array.t

type problem = { initial_grid : int option grid }

type available = { loc : int * int; possible : int list }

type state = { problem : problem; current_grid : int option grid; available = available list } 

let branch_state (state : state) : (state * state) option =
  if prazni_kvadratki state.current_grid = [] then
    None
  else
    let lst = prazni_kvadratki state.current_grid in  
    let loc = List.hd lst in
    let st1_grid = copy_grid state.current_grid in
    let st2_grid = copy_grid state.current_grid in
    match razpolozljive state.current_grid loc with
    | x :: xs -> (vstavi_vrednost st1_grid loc (Some x);
                  let st1 = {problem = state.problem; current_grid = st1_grid} in
                  match xs with
                  | [y] -> (vstavi_vrednost st2_grid loc (Some y);
                           let st2 = {
                             problem = state.problem; 
                             current_grid = st2_grid
                           })   (* this is where it shows me a syntax error*)
                  | y :: ys -> let st2 = {
                      problem = state.problem; 
                      current_grid = copy_grid state.current_grid; 
                      available = {loc = loc; possible = xs}
                    })
Some (st1, st2)
```

Comment: You don't show the error. But we can't try the code ourselves because you don't give a self-contained example.

Comment: The first syntax error you have is on line 7. `available = available list` should be `available : available list`.

Comment: A couple of semantic issues as well: `match` with only the pattern `x :: xs` will only match on a non-empty list, and is therefore not exhaustive. How does your program handle `razpolozljive state.current_grid loc` returning an empty list? If that's not "possible" a list may be the wrong data structure to use.

Comment: Looking at your match, we basically have `match some_list with x :: xs -> (match xs with [y] -> ... | y :: ys -> ...)`. This can be less complex as a single level match: `match some_list with x :: [y] -> ... | x :: y :: ys -> ...`.

Answer (score 2):

On around the 5th last line or so you have `let` with no matching `in`. The `let` expression always must have an `in`.

The basic rule for nested `match` is that you should use parentheses or `begin/end` around the inner one:

```
match x with
| [] -> 0
| [_] ->
   begin
   match y with
   | [] -> 1
   | _ -> 2
   end
| _ -> 3
```

Otherwise the final cases of the outer match look like they belong to the inner one. I don't think this is your problem here because you have no outer cases after the inner `match`.

Answer (score 1):

### Syntax issues

You have a few syntax issues.

```
type state = { problem : problem; current_grid : int option grid; available = available list }
```

You likely meant to have:

```
type state = { problem : problem; current_grid : int option grid; available : available list }
```

However, given how you construct values later in your program where you provide a value for the `available` field in one case but not in the other, you may want a variant type that allows your `state` type to be constructed with or *without* this value, with distinct behavior when not constructed with this value. This might look like:

```
type state = 
| With_available of { problem : problem; 
                      current_grid : int option grid; 
                      available : available list }
| Without_available of { problem : problem; 
                         current_grid : int option grid }
```

The other syntax issue is missing an `in` to go with a `let` which brings us to:

### Scoping issues

There are clearly some miunderstandings here for you in regards to how scope works with let bindings in OCaml.

Aside from a definition at the topmost level of a program, all let bindings are *local* bindings. That is, they apply to a single expression that trails an `in` keyword.

Consider this toplevel session.

```
# let x = 5;;
val x : int = 5
# let y =
    let x = 42 in
    x + 3;;
val y : int = 45
# x;;
- : int = 5
#
```

Here the `x` bound with `let x = 42 in x + 3` is only in scope for the duration of the expression `x + 3`. Once we're done with that expression, that binding for `x` is gone. In the outer scope, `x` is still bound to `5`.

In both cases in your `match` you bind names `st1` and `st2`, which would have to be local bindings, but then you try to use them in an outer scope, where they *don't exist*.

If you want `st1` and `st2`, you'd need to bind them in a similar way to `a` and `b` in the below simple example.

```
# let (a, b) = match [1; 2; 3] with
  | [x] -> (x, x)
  | x :: y :: _ -> (x, y)
  | _ -> (1, 1)
  in
  a + b;;
- : int = 3
#
```

### Pattern-matching

Please also note that the pattern-matching you're shown is not exhaustive. It does not handle an empty list. If you consider it impossible that an empty list will be a result, you still have to *either* handle it anyway *or* use a different data structure than a list which can by definition be empty.

You've shown pattern-matching of the basic pattern:

```
match some_list with
| x :: xs -> 
  match xs with 
  | [y] -> ...
  | y :: xs -> ...
```

We can actually match against the two possibilities you've show in one level of `match`.

```
match some_list with
| x :: [y] -> ...
| x :: y :: ys -> ...
```

If you still need to address `y :: ys` as `xs` in the second case, we can readily bind that name with the `as` keyword.

```
match some_list with
| x :: [y] -> ...
| x :: (y :: ys as xs) -> ...
```